# Carry Forward Data for Each Case

Tags: time-series, spss, longitudinal

In SPSS, how do I pull forward longitudinal data to blank cells for each id?

Example:

```
ID Time Gender
1  1    M
1  2    .
1  3    .
2  1    F
2  2    .
2  3    .
3  1    .
3  2    F
3  3    .
```

How do I get to this?

```
ID Time Gender Gender_Recoded
1  1    M      M
1  2    .      M
1  3    .      M
2  1    F      F
2  2    .      F
2  3    .      F
3  1    .      .
3  2    F      F
3  3    .      F
```

and then once I am able to carry forward, is there a command to do the reverse like in example 3, 1 so that F will pull up?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! If one of the answers solves your problem, please select it as the solution (click the V next to it). Also please upvote any answers that you find useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `AGGREGATE` function to do this. You specify which variable to group by setting `/BREAK` and then create your aggregated variables using [Aggregate Functions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/syn_aggregate_functions.html#syn_aggregate_functions).

In this case, `FIRST()` will apply the first non-missing value within each `ID` to **all** the rows/observations with that same `ID`.  Since it takes the first **non-missing** value, it both "carries forward" and "carries backward" the `Gender` value associated with each `ID` (solving both your cases).

```
AGGREGATE
 /OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
 /BREAK=ID
 /Gender_Recoded=FIRST(Gender) .
```

Comment: excellent solution - will also work with `max` instead of first.

Comment: You are brilliant!!!!  Thank you so much!!!!  Please post this on the internet - I spoke to so many people, searched for months trying to find this coding...even spoke to IBM SPSS Tech dept...Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped!  If one of the solutions provided answered your question please consider accepting it as the answer and/or upvoting any helpful answers for you.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution @user45392 suggested is perfect, but here is another nice one:

First we'll put the existing values in the first line of every ID, then for repeating ID's we copy gender value from the row above:

```
sort cases by ID gender (d). 
if ID=lag(ID) gender=lag(gender).
```

Comment: Thank you for this too.  I tried the lag earlier but did not know how to associate it by ID.  This really helps too!